# Only 7 parameters for kotlin function

Tags: android, kotlin, sonarqube

Sonarqube allows only 7 parameters for the function. I have a function that forms the string with 8 parameters.

```
fun example(
        context: Context,
        a: Int,
        b: Int,
        c: String,
        d: Int,
        e: String,
        list: List<String>,
        dat: String
) {
a = d+b
var f = a+b+d
if (list >0){
f = f+ "example"
}
return c+ e + f + dat
}
```

To make this function have only 7 parameters. I split the function by removing last parameter `dat` but in order to calculate `dat` variable I need `b` and `d` variables value also. So after function returns I need the value of `b` and `d` to evaluate `dat` and later concat `dat` to function return. Like below

```
fun example(
        context: Context,
        a: Int,
        b: Int,
        c: String,
        d: Int,
        e: String,
        list: List<String>
) {
a = d+b
var f = a+b+d
if (list >0){
f = f+ "example"
}
return c+ e + f
}

// i call it like below
example(context, 1, 1, "c", 1, "e", listOf('list1', 'list2')) + exampleConcat("dat text")

fun exampleConcat(dat: String) {
val t = d + b + dat  // here i need the latest value of 'd' and 'b'
return t
}
```

How do i get `d` and `b` latest value becoz after function returns these local variable will be destroyed?. How to make this function efficient by passing 7 arguments.

Comment: I think a better way to do it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535099/method-has-8-parameters-which-is-greater-than-7-authorized.

Comment: The restriction on number of parameters is because there's a possible design issue affecting code maintainability. If you solve it by making it more complicated (like hiding multiple parameters in a tuple or list), you're just making the issue worse. It would be preferable to ignore the Sonar warning than to dig a deeper hole.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom data model which would take multiple values.

like this

```
data class CustomModel(
var list:List<String>
var dat:String
)
```

Hence you solution will be something like this.

```
fun example(
        context: Context,
        a: Int,
        b: Int,
        c: String,
        d: Int,
        e: String,
        customModel:CustomModel
) {
a = d+b
var f = a+b+d
if (customModel.list >0){
f = f+ "example"
}
return c+ e + f + customModel.dat
}
```

Now you call your function example() and pass the CustomModel(list,dat) into your customModel param in the example function.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from a question - why more than 7 parameters in a function is a bad thing?

The answer is quite simple - it's all about readability.
So, what we can do about it?

**1. `Opts` object**

```kotlin
data class ExampleOpts(
    public val p1: String,
    ...
    public val p10: Int = 0
)

fun example(opts: ExampleOpts) {

}
```

This way is much more readable - the function signature suggests it has a lot of parameters, so it's a kind of good thing to extract them to its own structure.

**2. Builder**

When we reach such a number of parameters it may be good to somehow validate the data outside the method. We can do it using a builder. It's not common in kotlin, as a lot of pros of builder we can get using simply a data class (like default parameters etc.). However, sometimes it may be worthy, especially when we need to validate the data.

[Read more about Builder Pattern in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36140791/how-to-implement-builder-pattern-in-kotlin)

**3. Just ignore the issue :)**

In fact, we should not treat all issues in SonarQube (or any other linter) as a must-fix, because it's just a result of static analysis. Sometimes it's just a normal thing to have even more parameters. For example:

[example of functions with up to 22 parameters](https://github.com/MarioAriasC/funKTionale/blob/master/funktionale-currying/src/main/kotlin/org/funktionale/currying/namespace.kt)

As we can see in this library we have even more parameters than 7 and it's totally, totally fine.

**4. It's not about reducing the number of parameters, it's all about increasing the readability.**

Such a number of parameters suggest that there may be something wrong with an implementation. And a quick look at the implementation suggests it is.

```
fun example(
        context: Context,
        a: Int,
        b: Int,
        c: String,
        d: Int,
        e: String,
        customModel: CustomModel
) {
    a = d + b
    var f = a + b + d
    if (customModel.list > 0) {
        f = f + "example"
    }
    
    return c + e + f + customModel.dat
}
```

`context` - not used

`a` - won't compile, because `a` is redeclared at the very first line (`val cannot be reassigned`)

So, the number of parameters is not always a problem - it's just a suggestion, that something may be wrong. It's up to you to verify it and fix it if needed.

Comment: It's not just about readability, but also the single-responsibility principle. Having that many parameters is a sign of a possible design issue.